# dismantling, querying and reassembling generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method

```
T Get<T>(string key)
{..
}
```

If the caller calls me with `T = IEnumerable<V>` I need to do:

```
return GetEnum<V>(key)
```

Thus I need to

- test if T is `IEnumerable<X>`
- get X and shove it into the GetEnum
  method

I suspect that I cant do the second one

Obviously I can write a different method but thats not my contract with the existing code base.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a little reflection, but it won't be particularly fast:

```
static class TheClass
{
   public static T Get<T>(string key)
   {
      // Adjust these as required:
      const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

      if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(IEnumerable<>) == typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition())
      {
         Type v = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()[0];
         var baseMethod = typeof(TheClass).GetMethod("GetEnum", flags);
         var realMethod = baseMethod.MakeGenericMethod(v);
         return (T)(object)realMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { key });
      }

      // TODO: Handle other types...
   }

   private static IEnumerable<T> GetEnum<T>(string key)
   {
      // TODO: Return an enumerable...
   }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
If you want to check whether the required return type *implements* `IEnumerable<>`, you can use:

```
Type enumerable = typeof(T).GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1");
if (enumerable != null)
{
   Type v = enumerable.GetGenericArguments()[0];
   var baseMethod = typeof(TheClass).GetMethod("GetEnum", flags);
   var realMethod = baseMethod.MakeGenericMethod(v);
   return (T)(object)realMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { key });
}
```

However, your `GetEnum<V>` method will have to return a value which can be cast to `T`, otherwise you'll get an invalid cast exception.

For example, if your `GetEnum<V>` method returns `new List<T>(...)`, then your `Get<T>` method will only work if `T` is either `List<T>` or an interface implemented by `List<T>`. If you call `Get<HashSet<int>>`, it will fail.

Comment: almost there. The caller is calling me with a class derived from IEnumerable<T> (for example List<T>) (sry, not clear in the question), so the leading if doesnt work. I need 'is derived from IEnumerable, not is IEnumerable

Comment: @pm100: If your `GetEnum<T>` method is returning an `IEnumerable<T>` instance, you won't be able to cast that to a return type of `List<T>`.

Comment: i think i can by casting the return value to 'object' and then casting it to (T)

Comment: @pm100: I've updated my answer, but I still don't see how you expect it to work. The code will compile, but can still fail at runtime.